# Why do I get Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I installed wxWidgets 3.1.2 from source code on my computer with Fedora in /home/... And I am trying to build and run a Hello world example from https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html. It compiles without any error by typing

```
g++ widgetTest.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -o widgetTest
```

But after `./widgetTest` I get `./widgetTest: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` in my shell.

One answer in stackoverflow says to copy whole library in `/usr/lib` and I did it. Then it did not work and I got the same again.

(gtk2-devel and gtk3-devel I have already installed before installing wxWidgets)

`ldd ./widgetTest` returns:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeacdcf000)
libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.2 => not found
libwx_gtk2u_html-3.1.so.2 => not found
libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1.so.2 => not found
libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so.2 => not found
libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.2 => /lib64/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.2 (0x00007ffa3faea000)
libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so.2 => /lib64/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so.2 (0x00007ffa3fa9a000)
libwx_baseu-3.1.so.2 => /lib64/libwx_baseu-3.1.so.2 (0x00007ffa3f7e9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffa3f651000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffa3f4cd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffa3f4b2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffa3f490000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffa3f2ca000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ffa3f28b000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffa3f271000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffa3f26b000)
libsecret-1.so.0 => /lib64/libsecret-1.so.0 (0x00007ffa3f214000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa3f1be000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa3f09e000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ffa3f073000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffa3fb26000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007ffa3ef55000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ffa3ef32000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa3ed86000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007ffa3ed13000)
libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007ffa3ed06000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa3ed00000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ffa3ecd3000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ffa3ecb9000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib64/libmount.so.1 (0x00007ffa3ec5c000)
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007ffa3ebd4000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007ffa3eb81000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ffa3eb78000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffa3eb6e000)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output from `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`? And where did you install the library (in which directory is e.g. `libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.2`)?

Comment: Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the terminal before you execute the library

Comment: @MikevanDyke doesn't work (the same)

Comment: Am I right is `libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.2` a (kind of) dependency ?

Comment: It is a shared library that is used to build against the source file. The outupt of `wc-config...` has a `-lwx_gtk2u_xrc` flag (or other flat, we don't know, cause you didn't posted) which instructs gcc to link against the library. Check if you have the `libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so*` files on you system, in /usr/lib or /lib or /usr/lib64  or /usr/local/lib etc. If not, install it.

Comment: When you get around to edit your question to show the output of `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`, then also please show the output of `ldd ./widgetTest`.

Comment: @Антон, how did you configured and build wxWidgets? Please post the exact command used. Did you run `make install` afterwards? If you build them from source - can you successfully build the `minimal` sample?

Comment: @Igor minimal works. (yes, I run `make install` after `make`)

Comment: @KamilCuk `sudo dnf install libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1` returns "No match for argument"

Comment: @Антон, so what was you configure line exactly? Also did you run `ldconfig`? Just like `make install` asked..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` on the terminal before opening the executable (from the same terminal). To save having to do this each time, add that line to your ~/.bashrc or similar.
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started